# Objective C: How to retain gradient in navbar after adding custom background color?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, background-color

I changed the navbar background color using the following code

```
navconFvc.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"faf6f5"];
```

However, I realise that the gradient of the bar is now gone

[image]

How can I retain the gradient of the bar after the custom change of the bar's background color? I am hoping to be able to see a gradient effect like the original bar (like screenshot below)

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient is still there, you just can't see it because you have a near white tint. Use a darker tint and it'll be perceptible again. Now, if you want to change to a custom gradient for lighter backgrounds, then that's a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852319/uinavigationbar-gradient-details)